# `bg-gray-400` and `dark:bg-gray-100` are not changing anything

Tags: css, tailwind-css, astrojs

I'm trying to set a background color for a div in a component, for light and dark themes, but I'm not getting the result I expect.

On one side, `bg-gray-400` and `dark:bg-gray-100` are not changing anything.
Also,  `bg-[#2a2e35]` and `dark:bg-[#3b65ae]` shows color `#2a2e35` on dark mode.

```js
---
export interface Props {
  title: string;
  body: string;
  ogImage?: string;
  href: string;
  published: Date;
}

const { href, title, body, ogImage, published } = Astro.props;
---

<a href={href}>
  <div
    class="bg-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-100 w-full rounded-lg border shadow duration-200 ease-in hover:scale-105"
  >
    <img class="rounded-t-lg" src={ogImage} alt="" />
    <div class="p-5 bg-[#2a2e35] dark:bg-[#3b65ae]">
      <h5
        class="text-gray-900 dark:text-white mb-4 text-sm font-bold tracking-tight"
      >
        {title}
      </h5>
      <p
        class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 mb-12 text-sm font-normal"
      >
        {body}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

function withOpacity(variableName) {
  return ({ opacityValue }) => {
    if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
      return `rgba(var(${variableName}), ${opacityValue})`;
    }
    return `rgb(var(${variableName}))`;
  };
}

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}"],
  theme: {
    // Remove the following screen breakpoint or add other breakpoints
    // if one breakpoint is not enough for you
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      md: "768px",
      lg: "1024px",
      xl: "1280px",
    },

    // Uncomment the following extend
    // if existing Tailwind color palette will be used

    // extend: {
    textColor: {
      skin: {
        base: withOpacity("--color-text-base"),
        accent: withOpacity("--color-accent"),
        inverted: withOpacity("--color-fill"),
      },
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      skin: {
        fill: withOpacity("--color-fill"),
        accent: withOpacity("--color-accent"),
        inverted: withOpacity("--color-text-base"),
        card: withOpacity("--color-card"),
        "card-muted": withOpacity("--color-card-muted"),
      },
    },
    outlineColor: {
      skin: {
        fill: withOpacity("--color-accent"),
      },
    },
    borderColor: {
      skin: {
        line: withOpacity("--color-border"),
        fill: withOpacity("--color-text-base"),
        accent: withOpacity("--color-accent"),
      },
    },
    fill: {
      skin: {
        base: withOpacity("--color-text-base"),
        accent: withOpacity("--color-accent"),
      },
      transparent: "transparent",
    },
    fontFamily: {
      mono: ["Open Sans", "sans-serif"],
    },
    // },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
};
```

I want to have color `#3b65ae` on dark theme and `#2a2e35` on light theme.

I'm not very used to Tailwind but I'm doing what I saw in some documentation.

[Light Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJf3o.png)
[Dark Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNO4o.png)

**Update 26/02**
If I change the theme (light or dark) from the macOS system, the Card component is shown as expected, crazy.

Comment: Your code is right, check your config file (`tailwind.config.js`), also are other classes like `text-sm` and  `font-normal` working and behaving correctly?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour thanks for your reply! I added tailwind.config.cjs. Also, text and font seems to be working fine.

Comment: Try to delete your CSS file (that Tailwind produces) and recompile. Also does uncommenting `extend` change anything? Also adding `const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')` at the top of `tailwind.config.cjs` change anything?

Comment: Consider checking that the file the code is in is covered by the Tailwind configuration `content` file globs.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour 

- How do I find Tailwind file produces? I don't know where is it
- Uncomment `extend` does NOT change anything
- Adding colors dependency does NOT change anything

Comment: @Wongjn sorry for my ignorance, but how can I do that?

Comment: @Fermento Look in the `content` array of file globs in `tailwind.config.js`, `tailwind.config.cjs` or `tailwind.config.mjs` and determine if any of them match the path of the file that the code is in.

Comment: @Wongjn yes, the code is for a component called `Card.astro` inside `src/components`. The content is `["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}"]`

Answer (score 0):

In your config you have commented out `extend` so all the config changes are applied to the theme and the usual default theme settings are lost. You are effectively saying, these are the only values that I want to accept.

Instead you should add the custom config inside `extend`, so you keep the default Tailwind CSS theme config and add the additional settings.

Hence the comment in the config:

> Uncomment the following extend
> if existing Tailwind color palette will be used

Updated config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

function withOpacity(variableName) {
  return ({ opacityValue }) => {
    if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
      return `rgba(var(${variableName}), ${opacityValue})`
    }
    return `rgb(var(${variableName}))`
  }
}

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '1024px',
      xl: '1280px',
    },

    // Uncomment the following extend
    // if existing Tailwind color palette will be used

    extend: {
      textColor: {
        skin: {
          base: withOpacity('--color-text-base'),
          accent: withOpacity('--color-accent'),
          inverted: withOpacity('--color-fill'),
        },
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        skin: {
          fill: withOpacity('--color-fill'),
          accent: withOpacity('--color-accent'),
          inverted: withOpacity('--color-text-base'),
          card: withOpacity('--color-card'),
          'card-muted': withOpacity('--color-card-muted'),
        },
      },
      outlineColor: {
        skin: {
          fill: withOpacity('--color-accent'),
        },
      },
      borderColor: {
        skin: {
          line: withOpacity('--color-border'),
          fill: withOpacity('--color-text-base'),
          accent: withOpacity('--color-accent'),
        },
      },
      fill: {
        skin: {
          base: withOpacity('--color-text-base'),
          accent: withOpacity('--color-accent'),
        },
        transparent: 'transparent',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        mono: ['Open Sans', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
}
```

When you use arbitrary values like `bg-[#2a2e35]` they will explicitly get added to your CSS, but with your original config values like `bg-gray-400` get ignored, because the theme settings no longer recognised that as a valid `backgroundColor` name.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/acF17VawCs?file=config

Comment: I uncommented `extend` on the configuration but nothing happens. Something curious I saw is that the only thing is not changing is this card component, the rest of the site is changing. Also, if I change the theme through macOS. system, the card shows as expected, crazy !

Comment: I would point out that with the supplied code you will only see the background of the div with `p-5 bg-[#2a2e35] dark:bg-[#3b65ae]` but if you remove the background color you should see the `bg-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-100` working. https://play.tailwindcss.com/lR1CAbrvol

Comment: you are right but no matter which one I use, the color is blocked stuck at the dark definition no matter if I'm on light or dark theme. In other words, light mode color is ignored.